# PHPExcel saving template with an excessive file size

Tags: php, phpexcel

Version information:

PHPExcel - 1.7.8

linux - Linux version 2.6.18-274.12.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51))

PHP Version - 5.3.17

I have a sales reporting template that I use to create a weekly report.  Everything works perfectly, except for the output file size.

The input template is only 249kb in size, and yet the output file ends up being over 4mb in size.

There are a total of 97 cells that have any data put added into them.  When I insert the data manually, the size stays correct.

Original Template size - 254,464

Manual Entry Output size - 254,464

PHPExcel Output size - 4,230,656

I based my code off of the 30template.php example.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this is appreciated!

If any other information is needed I'll respond with what I can.

Comment: you could always compress it with gzip

Comment: Didn't you ask this in the PHPExcel forum?

Comment: I should point that Excel can parse XHTML. If your reports don't include macros or any extremely complicated formulas, opening an HTML file which consists of a  < table >  in excel works like a charm

Comment: There's not a need to compress it though.  If I add the data by hand the file size stays the same as the template, but when the data is added with PHPExcel, it grows to over 4mb in size.

Comment: Yes, I posted it on the PHPExcel forum first as it specifically had to do with them, but a lot more people visit here.  The report script is just grabbing numerical data from an sql database, importing the excel template, writing the data into the correct cells, then saving the file in a different location.

Comment: It's amazing how a question that is understood and answered by the developer of the code it's referring to was closed b/c it was a question that couldn't be answered.  Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the worksheet contains the data that you expect, then you really shouldn't worry about this. 4MB isn't particularly large for a file.

PHPExcel is not a file editor: it doesn't simply add a few extra cells into the original file that might simply add a few bytes to the resultant size. It loads the file, converting its content to a PHPExcel object; you modify that PHPExcel object; and when you save, it writes a new file from the content of that PHPExcel object. Excel itself has a lot of different options for the way it stores the spreadsheet data, and the resources to optimise to store them extremely efficiently when it saves. PHPExcel stores in a generic manner, without the overhead of determining how best to optimise the resultant file to a minimal size. PHPExcel may, for example, save additional default styles that aren't used in the workbook, whereas Excel itself may discard these. You don't mention which format you're using: .xlsx or .xls... the former is zip compressed; but the zip compression method used by ZipArchive may not match the compression method used by Excel.

So there's a whole host of factors that come into play that affect the size of a saved file: what's generally more important is that the content is correct.

Comment: I think I understand it a bit better now.  The format I'm using is the .xls (Excel5). I would switch over to the .xlsx format since everyone here is upgrading to office 2010, but I don't know if Starbucks has upgraded yet, heh.  The part that really threw us off about the file size is some of us received the file as a 4mb file, others 6mb, and even one person got it at over 10mb.  Which is really weird, because we're all being emailed the same file.  So, there really isn't a way to keep the file size down at the normal size, but as long as the data is correct I shouldn't have to worry?

Comment: It's odd that identical files are producing different sized results: while even something as simple as using 64-bit PHP can provide a different output file to template file; but the same code producing different sized files from the same script and data on the same platform is disconcerting to me (as the developer). However, in general, the content should be what matters, and as long as that is correct then that's the important thing.

Comment: How are you measuring filesize though? On a windows box, you can get two figures for filesize. One is the actual number of bytes in the file. The second is the amount of disk space that it takes, depending on the formatting of the disk.

Comment: I'm using the 'Size' field, not the 'Size on Disk' for all the files.  Another odd thing I found, if I open one of the 4mb files in excel, then 'save as' under a different name, it then saves as 2.7mb.  The way I have the script working, is it imports the data from a txt file into an array, then imports the template, inserts the data into the cells, then saves the excel file in another location. Then the script grabs that file and sends it out in an email. So the saved file is 4mb, it's just the attachments through zend that are coming to different sizes.

Comment: The difference when you save with Excel is that it will be saving optimised, but may well still be saving some of the "default" elements that are included in every PHPExcel save, but that were not present in the original template file at all.

Comment: I can't really explain the differences when ZF mails the attachments, but I'm not a Zend expert